# Jasmine spyOn on ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click test is failed

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Trying to test React component, using Karma+Jasmine,
I'm trying to check that all function into `onClick` handler is invoked, but the test return false result:

```
`Expected spy reportLoginWithEmail to have been called.`
```

Here is my component:

```
<a className="sign-in-with-email" onClick={this.signInWithEmail}>
   Or Sign in with your Email
</a>
```

signInWithEmail handler:

```
signInWithEmail = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    isEmailSignIn: true
  });
  biActions.reportLoginWithEmail(); 
};
```

Test:

```
  describe('SignIn', () => {
  let component, biActions;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SignIn/>);
    biActions = require('../../../actions/BIActions');

    spyOn(biActions, 'reportLoginWithEmail');
  });

  it('test clicking on login by email call function', () => {
    let signInEmail =       TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(component, 'sign-in-with-email');
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(signInEmail);
    expect(biActions.reportLoginWithEmail).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

On another side the test of `state` change return `true` :

```
it('test clicking on login by email change state', () => {
    let signInEmail = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(component, 'sign-in-with-email');
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(signInEmail);
    expect(component.state.isEmailSignIn).toBe(true);
  });
```

What am I missing, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after few hour of research i found the problem:

`require` order of your components is very important and that was my problem.

On the top of test  `SignIn` component was imported:

```
import SignIn from '../components/SignIn;
```

and only after that I `mock` `reportLoginWithEmail` in `beforeEach` that was already initialized in `SignIn` component, `it` block checked if `mock`'ed function was invoked while `SignIn` component called to non `mock`'ed function,

so the issue has been resolved by change order of `require` and remove `import` of `SignIn` component on the top of test, working code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    biActions = require('../../../actions/BIActions');

    spyOn(biActions, 'reportLoginWithEmail');

    SignIn = require('../../../components/LoginPage/SignIn');
    LoginByEmail = require('../../../components/LoginPage/LoginByEmail');

    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SignIn/>);
  });
```

in that case `SignIn` component initialized with `mock`'ed `reportLoginWithEmail` function